# Spring Integration - Joining messages from 2 channels

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration and want to know if there exist a component in Spring Integration which will help me in joining the results of 2 channels. I know the answer would  be aggregator, however I don't want messages to be merged into 1 message but they should flow to the downstream component when messages from both the channels have arrived. It is sort of Cyclic Barrier case.

Thank You
Adi

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the `aggregator` is to aggregate the released group of messages into a single message with a collection in the payload.

You can add a `splitter` after the aggregator to bust them up again.

However, if the aggregator output `MessageGroupProcessor` produces a `Collection<Message<?>` then each message is released one after the other.

You can't wire in a custom `MessageGroupProcessor` using the XML configuration but you can do so when configuring in Java...

```
AggregatingMessageHandler aggregator = new AggregatingMessageHandler(new FooProcessor());
...


private class FooProcessor implements MessageGroupProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object processMessageGroup(MessageGroup group) {
        return group.getMessages();
    }

}
```